# How to convert decimal to binary in excel without using the engineering functions

Tags: excel, binary, int, decimal, modulo

I am trying to learn the fundamentals behind the conversion of binary to decimal/Hex/Oct. For now I am focusing on decimal to binary conversion, **without** the use of the engineering functions dec2bin. I haven't found much online regarding this.

Thus far I have figured out how to convert a cell with a positive decimal number inside of it into 8 boxes (8 bits) making up 0's and 1's.

The way I have done this is using the MOD and INT functions.

[First bit with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqT8Y.png)

[2nd Bit with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmEpL.png)

In the above two images I show how I manually calculate the process of converting from decimal to binary. The question is, this is the long way of doing it and I would like help to make it so that it is simply two boxes; one with a decimal and the other with the binary, so that when I enter the decimal it is instantly calculated into the binary beside it, as demonstrated in picture 3.

[decimal to binary short form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ar75.png)

If anyone could help me understand how to make my formula work using just one cell instead of 8 separate and different formulaes, it would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the fomula in H3?

Comment: @ScottCraner =INT(MOD(A3/4,2)) & then G3 is =INT(MOD(A3/8,2)) & F3 is =INT(MOD(A3/16,2)) & E3 is =INT(MOD(A3/32,2)) & D3 is =INT(MOD(A3/64,2)) & C3 is =INT(MOD(A3/128,2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CONCAT as an Array formula:

```
=CONCAT(INT(MOD(A3/2^(8-ROW($1:$8)),2)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

CONCAT was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

[image]

---

If one does not have Concat, this can be done with TEXT and SUMPRODUCT:

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(INT(MOD(A3/2^(8-ROW($1:$8)),2))*(10^(8-ROW($1:$8)))),"00000000")
```

[image]

Comment: It's okay, my excel comes with concatenate, a smaller q here, could you explain this part of the formula " 2^(8-ROW($1:$8)),2))) " just to consolidate my understanding, also what difference is there when dealing with signed decimal values in the range of -128 to 128?

Comment: Top the first: the Row(1:8) creates and array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` the formula then iterates those doing the math `2^7`,`2^6`,...,`2^0`.  As to the second I do not know. Not a math guy, just made your formula into an array formula.

Comment: But according to my test you will need to enlarge it to a 10 digit return.  So change the `8`s to `10` in both formula and the `"00000000"` to `"0000000000"` and it will return the same as `dec2bin`

Comment: cheers for the heads up. I'll make mention of it in my report during testing. cheers again.