# Can you help me make a table for number conversions?

Tags: excel

Can someone help me create a table where I have to convert decimal numbers to binary, octal and hex?

Here is a picture of where an error is...

[image]

#NUM! is the error btw. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Dec2Bin has a limit of `-511` to `511`  If you want more you will need to write vba.  There are many examples on code on this site.

Comment: Here is a formula method.  You can try to make it work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862775/how-to-convert-decimal-to-binary-in-excel-without-using-the-engineering-function